# Cant get my borders to be positioned

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
    background-image: url("https://wallpapertag.com/wallpaper/full/8/5/a/157291-vertical-minecraft-shaders-background-1920x1080-ios.jpg");
}
.title {
    font-size:50px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    left: 790px;
}
.title {
    position: relative;
}
.text {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 10px;
}
.nfa {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top: 65px;
    background-color:black|50%;
}
.sfa {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top: 65px;
    background-color:black;
}
.of {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left:750px;
    margin-bottom: 500px;
    background-color:black;
    position: absolute;
}
.text-desc {
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.buttonnfa {
    background-color: #09ebf7;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}
.buttonsfa {
    background-color: #09ebf7;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}
.buttonof {
    background-color: #09ebf7;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}
.buttonnfa:hover{
    background-color:#05a2aa;
}
.buttonsfa:hover{
    background-color:#05a2aa;
}
.buttonof:hover{
    background-color:#05a2aa;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> SpeedyAlts </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='bg'>
            <a class="title"> SpeedyAlts </a>
            <div class="nfa">
                <center>
                    <a class="text"> NFA Account </a>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <a class="text-desc"> Minecraft accounts with security questions which you can use to log in and play on. </a>
                </center>
                <a class="buttonnfa" data-selly-product="a0f2e42d"> Purchase </a>
            </div>

            <div class="sfa">
                <center>
                    <a class="text"> SFA Account </a>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <a class="text-desc"> A Minecraft account without security questions with the ability to change username, skin and password. </a>
                </center>
                <a class="buttonsfa" data-selly-product="a0f2e42d"> Purchase </a>
            </div>

            <div class="of">
                <center>
                    <a class="text"> Optifine Cape </a>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <a class="text-desc"> A Minecraft account without security questions with the ability to change username, skin and password. </a>
                </center>
                <a class="buttonof" data-selly-product="a0f2e42d"> Purchase </a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script src="https://embed.selly.gg"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have got no idea why it is not working. For some reason with margin-top margin-left etc. It's not moving it up nor down with any of the margins. Could Anyone help? I am not that good at HTML nor with CSS so excuse any code that is badly formatted if there is any. Also, if anyone could give me any advice on problems like this in the future that would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking here. Which element is "not moving up nor down with any of the margins"?

Comment: The div class "of" is not moving with margins.

Comment: use top:.. & bottom:.. properties for an absolute positioned div.

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` in question has `position:absolute`. You will need to either remove this, or use `top` and `bottom`, `left` and `right` to move it on the page. In your example, if you'd like to move the element up on the page you will need to declare:

```
.of {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color:black;
    position: absolute;
    left:750px;
    bottom: 500px;
}
```

Please keep in mind this means your element will always be 500px from the bottom and 750px from the left. It is better to use percentage values.

Comment: In general, I'd recommend studying the `position: ` property before even doing any of the CSS coding. It's vital to understanding and any future styling ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position )

Comment: Done that, I forgot to mention I am trying to move it up but it's failing to move up.

Comment: @AvatarPlomo  if you want to move an element up, when it has relative or absolute positioning, simply use the `bottom:` property. For example `bottom: 50px` moves the picture 50 pixels up. Alternatively you can use top with negative value `top: -50px`

Answer (score 0):

To move it up, you can try one of these to the class `.of` :

**Margin approach**

```
margin-top:-50px;
```

**Absolute positioning approach**

```
top: 300px; //change this value as needed
```

**Transform approach**

```
transform:translateY(-50px);
```